# Unique icons next to each Wordpress menu item

Tags: php, wordpress, function, navigation

I have Wordpress menus that is seems are put together in the backend somehow. I used [wp_nav_menu()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_nav_menu/) to customize the wrap of the menu items slightly.

My issue is I have found no direct access to access the menu items, and add a custom field to them. They are all categories, and I want a specific icon for each category.

This is my code in the functions.php to customize the menu:

```
function custom_novice_menu($args) {
    $args['container'] = false;
        $args['container_id'] = 'my_primary_menu';
        $args['link_before'] = '<div class="topic-card"><div class="topic-circle"></div><h3>';
        $args['link_after'] = '</h3></div>';
    return $args;
}
```

Does anyone know a way I could add a unique icon to each menu item? Preferably with a way other than CSS.